# Why does Angular 7 single page app auto refresh time to time?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 single page app. Noticing an issue with that. Some times it automatically refreshes. We don't have any code written to reload/refresh it. This might be happening when there is a sudden drop of internet. But not sure whether that is the exact cause. It only happens for our app. Other browser tabs I have opened in the same browser nothing happens. Do you have any idea what could be causing this automatic page refresh?

UPDATE : This refresh is not due to code changes. I have deployed the app in our server and we are just using it. Not doing any code changes/updates at all. Basically this happens when we are using the app. Nothing to do with development.
I am using this command to serve
ng serve --configuration=source --aot

Comment: If you're seeing this in development, this is how the Angular CLI tools work, when you change the source code it refreshes in the browser.

Comment: Hi Madhu, is your app built with `ng build --prod` ?

Comment: @mikegross I am using this ng serve --configuration=source --aot

Comment: you shouldn't serve your app in production with ng serve. ng serve is for development. not deployment

Comment: @JMK I have updated my question. This refresh is nothing to do with code changes.

Comment: @mikegross so if I use ng build --prod, then after that how do I run the app. Is there another command for that? If I use ng serve then I can open it like this http://192.168.8.106:4200/ but when build with ng build --prod not sure how to run it. Thanks

Comment: @bryan60 ok thanks. Can you please reply to my above comment.

Comment: You have to deploy your compiled code using `ng build --prod` to your servers, if you just run ng serve on your servers you are letting users work with a dev build and you might have missed issues/bugs, also the hot reload is enabled....

Comment: @mikegross ok thank you very much. But when I build it like that how do I run the app. Is there another command for that? Please see my comment above. I am new to Angular so don't have much idea about it.

Comment: this is an entire new topic, you should read https://angular.io/guide/deployment since it is very specific to what server you use and its configuration

Comment: @mikegross ok thank you. Was able to get it deployed in Beanstalk following this https://medium.com/@diuke/deploying-angular-webapps-with-nodejs-to-amazon-web-services-elastic-beanstalk-fa271a4542ea

Answer (score 0):

This happen because Angular starts the server with the flag --liveReload set to true by default, it makes reload the page whenever it detects a change in your code.
If you don't want this behavior, set it to false when you start the server with ng serve.